# 2 Codeigniter Installations on the same server with subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

### I have the following scenario:

A Codeigniter Website (Lets call it **WebA**) is installed on the root of the sebserver "/", accessed from the domain: www.example.com.

Another Codeigniter Website (Lets call it **WebB**) is installed in the same webserver in a subfolder "/subfolder", accessed from the domain: www.example2.com.

I have 2 .htacces files that remove the index.php, installed on WebA and in WebB:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (auth|register|secure)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(static|auth|register|secure)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/octet-stream .otf .ttf
```

I have configured on WebA in /application/config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

And in WebB in /subfolder/application/config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example2.com/';
```

### Error 1:

With This configuration when I access www.example2.com I get:

404 Page Not Found

### Error 2:

If I change WebB's .htaccess RewriteBase line to:

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/
```

I get the html outputted, in the index "http://example2.com/" but it will not load any of my JS or CSS, because instead of loading the script it loads this:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/html.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 60</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/subfolder/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/url_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 546</p>

</div>
```

It also outputs this error when trying to navigate the pages but I get no Html.

The first error seems to be because of the missconfiguration my database models are not working.

### Error 3:

If I change WebB's config.php to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/subfolder/';
```

And WebB's RewriteBase line in .htaccess to:

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/
```

Its working fine, when accessed by www.example.com/subfolder/ and www.example2.com, but the problem are the WebB's links, which I need them to be as www.example2.com and not www.example.com/subfolder/

WebA is always working.

I have the same code working on multiple websites without any problems, but I have never faced this scenario before. Any ideas?

Comment: I've never done this type of work with CI but I know CI lets you to have more applications than one in the same system. I just know that you can create more application folders with their proper name and then configure CI to correct routing. It might be worthy if you check this type of attempt in CI's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got this working, what I did:

I asked my system administrator to change all the websites to use Virtualhosts as [Hicham LEMGHARI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1760291/hicham-lemghari) sugested, but I dont know if he did it right because I still had the errors on WebB:

WebA installed in /var/www/subfolderA

WebB installed in /var/www/subfolderB

### WebA

WebA's htaccess file configured RewriteBase line as:

```
RewriteBase /subfolderA/
```

And config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

### WebB

WebB's htacces file changed completely to just these 4 lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And config.php to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example2.com/';
```

Comment: I believe this was different from the starting ' One App is on another App folder' strategy. Glad you solved it though.

Comment: Yes, I made a lot of changes untill I got it working with this method, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Using virtualhosts with your installation can save you from the pain of configuring .htaccess.

Comment: I tried this, but I dont know if the system administrator did this correctly because I still had the same problem, I created 2 subfolders (subfolderA, subfolderB) under /var/www/ but I still had configuration issues with WebB under subfolderB, I will awnser my own question with the changes I did to get this working.

Comment: Without your Administrator 'code' to do that, I can't tell, I'm using this for my blog and my wiki under /wiki and /blog without problems