# remove index.php from url codeigniter when put in sub folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i want to remove index.php from url . i put codeigniter file in  subfolder

```
http://192.168.2.8/mydomain_folder/subdomain_folder/index.php/admin_controls
```

want to get it as

```
   http://192.168.2.8/mydomain_folder/subdomain_folder/admin_controls
```

.htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_staging/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

where to place the .htacess files

I put 1 at the root folder and another inside application folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 Codeigniter Installations on the same server with subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385423/2-codeigniter-installations-on-the-same-server-with-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in top of your .htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Put it in root folder where index.php is available.
test on your server have mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Find `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` and remove the variable 'index.php' form `/root/codeigniter/config/config.php` you rewrite looks good.